# Unity 3D Scriptable Render Pipeline: DrawRenderers Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some trouble using the DrawRenderers function in a custom render pass. I have this execute function for my pass:

```
public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
{
    CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("VisibilityPass");
    SortingSettings ss = new SortingSettings(renderingData.cameraData.camera) {
        criteria = SortingCriteria.BackToFront
    };
    DrawingSettings drawSettings = new DrawingSettings(new ShaderTagId("UniversalForward"), ss) {
        overrideShader = visibilityShader
    };
    FilteringSettings filteringSettings = FilteringSettings.defaultValue;
    cmd.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, new Color(0, 0, 1, 1));
    context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
    
    context.DrawRenderers(renderingData.cullResults, ref drawSettings, ref filteringSettings);
    context.Submit();
    CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
}
```

It is supposed to render the scene into a rendertexture with a shader override on each object (In this scene all objects should be a solid black while the cube is a solid red) I have the RenderTexture shown in the top left of the screen. It works fine most of the time (first image) but the sorting seems to be wrong whenever the camera and cube are on opposite sides of the plane's center (second image).

I think this might be an issue with my SortingSetting but I'm really not sure. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Thank You!

Working Correctly

[image]

Not Working Correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the camera's depth? May be this could be the reason of your issue. Also check if there are interferences between override shader and the depth information and also try to use the Graphics Debugger tool to indetify anomalies.